# How to prepend a "string" to a "string[]" variable?

Tags: powershell

Let's suppose I have a PowerShell function that returns a `[string[]]`:

```
function do_something() {
    [string[]]$str_array = @("one", "two", "three")
    return $str_array
}

$x = do_something()

# doesn't work
$y = @("something", $x)
```

Now I want to prepend a string to the front of the `[string[]]` list.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `@("something"; $x)`. And, BTW, your function does not return array, but three separate strings. `$x` will be `[object[]]`, but not `[string[]]`.

Comment: changing "," to a ";" works like a charm.  That's interesting, I wasn't aware that a "," is different from a ";" when forming a list...

Answer (score 0):

There are several [ways](http://www.powershellish.com/blog/2014-12-09-join-arrays) to join two arrays. Regarding your question in the above comment:

> That's interesting, I wasn't aware that a "," is different from a ";" when forming a list...

In PowerShell, the `,` is an own operator, where its behavior differs if used in a unary or binary statement.

From [about_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#comma-operator-):

> As a binary operator, the comma creates an array. As a unary operator, the comma creates an array with one member. Place the comma before the member.

In the code `@("something", $x)` you're using the operator in binary form. So a new array with two entries is created. The first entry is the string "something", the second entry contains an array of strings. Thats because PowerShell interprets it as: "Ok, I shall create a new array with two entries (="something", and a reference pointing to an array).

We can check that with the help or `Get-Member`:

```
C:\> $y | Get-Member          


TypeName: System.String
    Name             MemberType            Definition
    ----             ----------            ----------
    Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
    ...


    TypeName: System.Object[]
    Name           MemberType            Definition
    ----           ----------            ----------
    Add            Method                int IList.Add(System.Object value)
    ...
```

As can be seen, `Get-Member` shows use two `TypeName`s. The first is a string, the second is an array.

When changing the code to `@("something"; $x)` no `,`-operator is used anymore. Instead, the code is now split up in about three "command", since the command-separator (=`;`) is used.

- Cmd1: "something"
- Cmd2: $x -> which dumps the array content
- Cmd3: @() -> guarantees that the expressions inside the brackets are returned as an array.

You can also remove the command seperator and define `$y` over multiple lines:

```
PS C:\>$y = @("something"
>>>      $x
>>>     )
```

The be less ambiguous I'd recommend to merge two arrays in the following way:

```
    PS C:\> $a = 1
    PS C:\> $b = @(2,3,4)
    PS C:\> $c = @()
    PS C:\> $c += $a
    PS C:\> $c += $b
    PS C:\> $c
    1
    2
    3
    4
    PS C:\> $c | gm


    TypeName: System.Int32
    Name        MemberType Definition
    ...
```

Of course, it's "more" code, but its less ambiguous.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @pico if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.